# Deployment of custom DFS (Documentum Foundation Services) on Jboss 6

Tags: jboss6.x, documentum-dfs

I am testing deployment of a custom DFS on JBOSS 6. However I am getting some errors when I deploy the application. The application is running fine with no error on JBOSS 5. However when I deploy the same DFS application on JBOSS 6 I am getting the following error message: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" "Could not initialize class com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient". The class it is complaining about is part of the dfc.jar file which I have added to [JBOSS-Home]/server/default/lib folder.

I added all the Documentum jar files to [JBOSS-Home]/server/default/lib folder, with no luck. The same jar files are also in the ear file's lib folder.

The server was restarted after adding the jar files.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is "Could not initialize class com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient". Either it is something wrong with your dfc.properties or the DFC is not able to create files during the DFC initializing caused maybe by wrong file permissions. During the initialization a lot of things are performed like logon to the Global Registry, creating a dfc.keystore side-by-side to the dfc.jar, registering this keystore inside the Global Registry, fetching other information from this Global Registry and storing first data into the persistent DFC cache.

Comment: The dfc.properties file contents are ok exactly the same as that of the service deployed on jboss 5 pointing to the same global registry. If its permission, it would be permission where? I deployed the same ear file on wildfly12 and I am getting the same error. Even base dfs is giving the same error.

Comment: The DFC cache is by default a directory named "documentum" located in the current working directory. However best practice would be defining it in your dfc.properties. The dfc.keystore is created in the lib directory where your dfc.jar is located. Is there a stack trace underneath "Could not initialize ..." which indicates better what the reason is?